# Why is this element of an html generated in the wrong order?

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to replace the element `lienconj` by `new_label` with the following code

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
r = session.get('https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/aimer/1925', headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

temp2 = [tag.attrs['href'] for tag in soup.select('.lienconj')]
for i in range(len(temp2)):
    new_label_1 = '<label for = "' + str(i) + '">' + '<div class="boxed">Conjugaison</div>' + '</label>'
    new_label_2 = '<input id = "' + str(i) + '" type = "checkbox" class = "trigger">'          
    new_label = new_label_1 + new_label_2
    soup.select('.lienconj')[0].replace_with(BeautifulSoup(new_label)) 

format = open(r'E:\\test.html', 'w+', encoding = 'utf8')
format.write(str(soup.select_one('.wrapper')))
format.close()
```

It's clear from `new_label_1` that `<div class="boxed">Conjugaison</div>` is inside `<label for` and `</label>`. Could you please explain why the resulted html does not has this correct order?

Here is the excerpt from the resulted html `test.html`:

```
<p class="CatgramDefinition">verbe transitif <label for="10"></label></p>
```

Comment: See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element’s *content model*, or put the HTML you’re trying to generate into https://html5.validator.nu/, to find the problem.

Comment: @Ry- There is a related error `Unclosed element label`. I don't get it, because I already include `'</label>'` in my code. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: `<label>` can’t contain `<div>`, and `<p>` can’t contain `<div>` either.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ry-. Without you, I can never figure out how to solve this problem.